# loadGraph(): ERRORNot found: Failed to load compute graph at

Tags: c++, tensorflow

**I am trying to run a c++ project using tesorflow ! But  getting this error when loading the frozen_inference_graph.pb.**

**loadGraph(): ERRORNot found: Failed to load compute graph at '~/Desktop/Tensor/obdet/tensorflow-object-detection-cpp/demo/ssd_mobilenet_v1_egohands/frozen_inference_graph.pb'**

**How to solve it !**

**Source Code::**

```
string ROOTDIR = "~/Desktop/Tensor/obdet/tensorflow-object-detection-cpp/";
string LABELS = "demo/ssd_mobilenet_v1_egohands/labels_map.pbtxt";    
string GRAPH = "demo/ssd_mobilenet_v1_egohands/frozen_inference_graph.pb"; 
// Set input & output nodes names`
string inputLayer = "image_tensor:0";
vector<string> outputLayer = {"detection_boxes:0", "detection_scores:0", "detection_classes:0", "num_detections:0"};
// Load and initialize the model from .pb file
std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session;
string graphPath = tensorflow::io::JoinPath(ROOTDIR, GRAPH);
LOG(INFO) << "graphPath:" << graphPath;
Status loadGraphStatus = loadGraph(graphPath, &session);
 //LOG(INFO) << "graphPath:" << graphPath;
if (!loadGraphStatus.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "loadGraph(): ERROR" << loadGraphStatus;
    //return -1;
} else
    LOG(INFO) << "loadGraph(): frozen graph loaded" << endl;


// Load labels map from .pbtxt file
std::map<int, std::string> labelsMap = std::map<int,std::string>();
Status readLabelsMapStatus = readLabelsMapFile(tensorflow::io::JoinPath(ROOTDIR, LABELS), labelsMap);
if (!readLabelsMapStatus.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "readLabelsMapFile(): ERROR" << loadGraphStatus;
 //   return -1;
} else
    LOG(INFO) << "readLabelsMapFile(): labels map loaded with " << labelsMap.size() << " label(s)" << endl;
```

**Load Function :**

```
Status loadGraph(const string &graph_file_name,unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> *session) {
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
Status load_graph_status =
        ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_file_name, &graph_def);
if (!load_graph_status.ok()) {
    return tensorflow::errors::NotFound("Failed to load compute graph at '",
                                        graph_file_name, "'");
}
session->reset(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
Status session_create_status = (*session)->Create(graph_def);
if (!session_create_status.ok()) {
    return session_create_status;
}
return Status::OK();
}
```

Comment: Most likely reason is that your `graphPath` is wrong. Assuming the file is where you say it is then I would try replacing the `~` in `ROOTDIR` with an explicit path.

Comment: Yes ! graphpath was from! Thanks a lot :)